# How to change img on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have this code that displays small images in a table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class='change' id='c1'><img src='images/on.gif'/></td>
<td class='change' id='c2'><img src='images/on.gif'/></td>
<td class='change' id='c3'><img src='images/on.gif'/></td>
<td class='change' id='c4'><img src='images/on.gif'/></td>
<td></td>    
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I change the image of any one of the images in the table on click event. 
I've tried doing this but can't seem to get it working.

```
$(document).on('click', '.change', function() {
if (this.src == 'images/on.gif')
  this.src = 'images/off.gif';
else
  this.src = 'images/on.gif';
});
```

I've searched for this and yes I have found similar questions but I really can't seem to get it working.

Comment: this does not have src

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Comment: `this` is a td. The image has a src. You have answers now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.change` is not the image, it's the parent TD :

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.change', function () {
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        img.attr('src', (img.attr('src') == 'images/on.gif' ? 'images/off.gif' : 'images/on.gif'));
    });
});
```

Comment: @user182 - Try it now, the native `element.src` return absolute URL's, you should get the attributes value instead when comparing relative paths.

Comment: Sad to say that still didn't change anything!

Comment: Could you explain what that means?

Answer (score 2):

`.change` are the table cell elements, not the image elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.change img', function () {
```

Comment: @user182 what do you mean by "Doesn't work?"  Do you get an error?  What happens?

Comment: nothing happens, it doesn't change the image when I click on it

Comment: @user182 Try using `$(this).attr('src')` instead of `this.src` for comparison

Comment: Nope still doesn't seem to be working. The file paths are definitely correct as it actually displays the images in the table but that's about it. Sorry if I'm not being helpful, I'm still learning

Comment: @user182 can you link to your page, or better yet a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: I'll try jsfiddle and get back to you

Comment: @ExplosionPills Sorry for deleting the question. it was a colleague of my work who accidently wrote it with typo.Thanks  alot